# "./" added to form action (ASPNET WebForms)

Tags: c#, iis, webforms

Good day, I have 2 web servers running the same code on the same Database.

One server is fine;

```
<form action="blahblah.aspx">
```

But the second one automatically adds "./" in front of action.

```
<form action="./blahblah.aspx">
```

I was wondering how is this happening in IIS/Code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post actual form tag from aspx/master page? any of web application is hosted at different level like in virtual directory etc??